# Calcular total de quantidade, preço e desconto e o total dos totais

Tags: php, laravel

não consigo criar o resultado total de Quantidade * valor_unitario - desconto, e também a soma desses totais, da tabela que é relacionada.

**Model**

```
    public function servico()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Servico::class);
}

public function cliente()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Cliente::class, 'id', 'cliente_id');
}

public function ordemservico()
{
    return $this->hasOne(OrdemServico::class);
}
```

**Repository**

```
    public function exibir($id)
{
    $orcamento = Orcamento::where('id', $id)->with('cliente')->with('servico')->first();
    return $orcamento;
}
```

Na tabela relacionada with('servico'), se encontra as colunas, "quantidade, valor_unitario(decimal:8,2)", "desconto(decimal:8,2)" preciso multiplicar quantidade pelo valor_unitario e subtrair pelo desconto se existir, e somar todos os valores totais, pra exibir na VIEW o total de cada um, e o total de tudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você terá que utilizar uma consulta com o `selectRaw` ou `select(DB::raw sum(seucampo) as seurotulo)`.

Um exemplo da forma que fiz em um projeto;

```
$products = DB::table('products')
    ->join('order_product', 'products.id', '=', 'order_product.product_id')
    ->selectRaw('products.id, products.sku, products.name, products.brand, sum(order_product.quantity) as sales_quantity, products.stock')
    ->groupBy('products.sku')
    ->orderBy('sales_quantity', 'DESC')
    ->get();

return response()->json($products);
```

Documentação Laravel - Raw Expressions

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: top entendi, vou adaptar ao meu código, obrigado mano

Comment: Shooow man! Qualquer coisa estamos aí.